# Appending text below each line of data in Excel

Tags: excel

Is it possible to add text in a new line below each existing line of data? I would prefer to do this in Excel, but could use another program or website if required. For example, my current data is:

```
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
10.0.0.4
```

I want to add "Yes" under each line, making the result:

```
10.0.0.1
Yes
10.0.0.2
Yes
10.0.0.3
Yes
10.0.0.4
Yes
```

Comment: Use a text editor and replace \n (or whatever line endings you're using) with \nYes\n

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ for example, go to replace and replace `$` by `\nYes\n`. Make sure you've checked *Regular expression* search.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(1:1),2)=1,INDEX(A:A,INT(ROW(1:1)/2)+1),"Yes")
```

And copy down.

Or as @pnuts stated:

```
=IF(ISODD(ROW(1:1)),INDEX(A:A,INT(ROW(1:1)/2)+1),"Yes")
```

[image]

Comment: And shorter is better? :)  I would still use the `ISODD(ROW(1:1))` just so I do not have to worry where the first formula is placed.